# CAS set-up using restlet API to secure REST services

Tags: rest, spring-security, cas

I was trying to use it for Single sing on. I was able to successfully secure my web services/pages and want to extend it to my REST APIs (services) as well. I am using CAS 4.0.0.
I followed this link http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.0/protocol/REST-Protocol.html and change the web.xml as suggested and added the following jar to my CAS deployment WEB-INF/lib folder:

cas-server-integration-restlet-4.0.0.jar

org.restlet.jar

org.restlet.ext.spring.jar

org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar

The Call to the "v1/tickets" is reaching the restlet-frame work but I am getting a 404 error to my rest client

```
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 439
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 06 Nov 2014 13:12:46 GMT
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.2.2
```

Can you Please help me identify the issue with the set-up or point me to a detailed documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com).

The endpoint is in lower-case: can you try: /v1/tickets?

Comment: THanks for the reply. I used "v1/tickets" (Samll v1, the one in my web.xml) only and was gettign 404. It was a typo in my original message sorry for that. My understanding is the "cas-server-webapp-4.0.0.war" supplied should work for the rest scenarios if the jars listed in my original post are present in the WEB-INF/lib. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you need several jars and to add the Restlet servlet in the web.xml file. I highly recommend to follow this documentation: http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.0/installation/Maven-Overlay-Installation.html, not to miss any dependencies.